# Create an archive and add files in it before sending to client

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to create an archive with archiver and put some files in it. Client's side, an user will click on a button and it'll generate the archive (server's side).

I'm using Express.js, this is my server side code where the archive will be generated. I did something like this :

```
app.get('/export/siteoccupancy', function(req,res){      

    if(_.isEmpty(req.query)){
         res.status(404).send('requires a start and end date');
    }else{
        //getting paramas
        var sDate = req.query.startDate;
        var eDate = req.query.endDate;

    }

    var fs = require('fs');
    var archiver = require('archiver');

    var archive = archiver('zip');

    archive.on('err',function(err){
        res.status(500).send({error : err.message});
    });

    res.on('close',function(){
        console.log('Archive size : %d b',archive.pointer());
        return res.status(200).send('OK').end();
    });

    res.attachment('data-export.zip');

    archive.pipe(res);

    var stream = fs.createWriteStream("data-report.txt')");
    stream.once('open',function(fd) {
        stream.write('test1');
        stream.write('\n test2');
        stream.write('\n test3');
        stream.end();
    });

    archive.append(stream);

    archive.finalize();

});
```

This is totally new for me and I'd like to understand why the console tells me the stream file is empty ?

Error: append: entry name must be a non-empty string value
    at Archiver.append

Regards

Comment: See this [post](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html) i don't think you need `once('open', fn)`

Answer (score 3):

you can only append a readStream, because an archive can only take data from readstreams. You can use the method named archive.append, and you should pass as a second argument with the name property to name the file. Like so :

```
archive.append(myReadStream,{ name : 'myTest.txt'});
```